# Visualforce Charting question - Pie Chart

Tags: apex, visualforce

- I have a Visualforce page that houses some Visualforce charts.

  - A link on the Account navigates the user to a Visualforce page that
    has the charts and passes the AccountId parameter the URL.
  - I have 3 number fields on the Account object that I wish to summarize    in a nice pie chart.

  > public List getAccountRollUpAggregate() {
  >               List data = new List(); 
  >               for (Account a : [SELECT Name, of_Closed_Won_New_Business_Opps__c, of_Open_New_Business_Opps__c,
  >   of_Closed_Lost_New_Business_Opps__c FROM Account WHERE
  >   Id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')]) {
  >                 data.add(new PieWedgeData(Integer.valueOf(a.get('of_Closed_Won_New_Business_Opps__c')),
  >   Integer.valueOf(a.get('of_Open_New_Business_Opps__c')),
  >   Integer.valueOf(a.get('of_Closed_Lost_New_Business_Opps__c'))));
  >               }
  >               return data; 
  >           }

Where the wrapper class is:

```
// Wrapper class
    public class PieWedgeData {

        public String name { get; set; }
        public Integer data { get; set; }
        public Integer dataOpen {get; set;}
        public Integer dataCWNB {get; set;}
        public Integer dataCLNB {get; set;}
```

And the constructor is:

```
    public PieWedgeData(Integer dataOpen, Integer dataCWNB, Integer dataCLNB) {
        this.dataOpen = dataOpen; 
        this.dataCWNB = dataCWNB; 
        this.dataCLNB = dataCLNB; 
    }
}
```

The corresponding Visualforce I have so far is:

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="true">
        <apex:chart data="{!AccountRollUpAggregate}" width="900" height="400">
            <apex:legend position="left"/>
            <apex:pieSeries labelField="dataCWNB" dataField="dataCWNB" donut="50">
            </apex:pieSeries>
        </apex:chart>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

The piechart is displaying only 1 integer - and I am unclear how to simply get the three number fields from the account record and have them display in a pie chart.

In the other piecharts I have created using the structure before (wrapper class, constructor, some constructor methods etc), they are working as expected - they are returning a value for multiple records whereas for this simple piechart I want multiple values for but 1 record.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to still return multiple values, as each wedge is its own line item, so you'll need a different sort of wrapper here (or change how your data is laid out). For example, you might provide the data as:

```
public class DonutWedge {
    public String label;
    public Decimal value;
    public DonutWedge(String label, Decimal value) {
        this.label = label;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

 public DonutWedge[] getAccountRollUpAggregate() {
    DonutWedge[] results = new DonutWedge[0];
    results.add(new DonutWedge('Open', record.of_Closed_Won_New_Business_Opps__c));
    results.add(new DonutWedge('Open/New', record.of_Open_New_Business_Opps__c));
    results.add(new DonutWedge('Closed/Lost', record.of_Closed_Lost_New_Business_Opps__c));
    return results; 
 }
```

Which you'd then render as follows:

```
    <apex:chart data="{!AccountRollUpAggregate}" width="900" height="400">
        <apex:legend position="left"/>
        <apex:pieSeries labelField="label" dataField="value" donut="10" colorset="#f88,#8f8,#88f" />
    </apex:chart>
```

Here's an example that I built that demonstrates this code:

[image: Sample Pie Chart]

Comment: As always, THANK YOU so much for your fantastic efforts! Really helped me!

Comment: Is there a way we can add text inside the pie donut at center? Like total count?